# Using Gradle, how can I list just the JSON library of the Play framework as a dependency?

Tags: json, scala, gradle, playframework

I need to parse some complex JSON with Scala and put it in a case class. After googling, it appears the JSON library of the Play framework is my best bet. However, I don't want to use the entire framework. I found this advice:

> You don't have to install the full frameworks -- you can just list the json library as a dependency.

I'm using Gradle as a build tool but I really don't know how to do what he is suggesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following:

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.play/play-json
compile group: 'com.typesafe.play', name: 'play-json_2.11', version: '2.6.7'
```

Comment: I have now added this information to the [play-json README](https://github.com/playframework/play-json#getting-started). Thanks!

Comment: It is not clear where and how this `compile group...` line need to be implemented. Neither in the play-json README for new Gradle users. May you please indicate?